# Keep getting response code 500 in Cardpointe API call

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, httprequest, http-status-code-500

I keep getting a 500 response code in an API call to the Cardpointe gateway (cardconnect) any insight will help.
(I was able to verify the test credentials by just posting to the URL without the `auth` endpoint)

Here is my code in a Google apps script:

```
function myFunction() {

  var messagesUrl = "https://fts-uat.cardconnect.com/cardconnect/rest/auth";
  var cred = "testing:testing123";
    
  var payload = JSON.stringify({
  "merchid" : "496160873888",
  "account": "4788250000121443",
  "expiry": "1218",
  "cvv2": "123",
  "amount": "100",
  "phone": "15558889999",
  "capture": "y"
  });

  
  var options = {
    "method" : "put",
   "payload" : payload
  };
  
  options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(cred)
    },{
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(messagesUrl, options);
  
  Logger.log(res);
  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: `options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(cred)
    },{
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }` should be `options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(cred),
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  }`

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your intrest here is the API docs `https://developer.cardpointe.com/cardconnect-api` and here is the sandbox testing docs `https://developer.cardpointe.com/guides/cardpointe-gateway`

Comment: @TheMaster. Thanks that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(cred)
    },{
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
```

Here content type is not set to `options.headers`.

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const options ={};
options.headers = {    
"Authorization" : "Basic " + "b64"
},{
"Content-Type" : "application/json"
}
console.log(options)
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

`headers` should be a single object with multiple keys:

```
options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(cred),
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
```

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const options={}
options.headers = {    
"Authorization" : "Basic " + "b64",
"Content-Type" : "application/json"
}
console.log(options)
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
let a;
a = 1,3;
console.log(a);// no 3
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```